# trouble with results of .split(" ") in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, parsing, split

I am just starting to learn ruby and I am having troubles splitting my strings by spaces. 
First I read in my file and break them up by the newline character :

```
inputfile = File.open("myfile.in")
filelines = inputfile.read.split("\n")
```

Then I try to read each of the two numbers individually:

```
filelines.each_with_index {|val, index| do_something(val, index)}
```

Where *do_something* is defined as:

```
def do_something(value, index)
   if index == 0
    numcases = value
    puts numcases
  else
    value.split(" ")
    puts value
    puts value[0] #trying to access the first number 
    puts value[1] #trying to access the second number 
  end
end
```

but with a smaller input file like this one,

```
42
4 2
11 19
0 10
10 0
-10 0
0 -10
-76 -100
5 863
987 850
```

My outputs ends up looking like this:

```
42
4 2
4

11 19
1
1
0 10
0

10 0
1
0
-10 0
-
1
0 -10
0

-76 -100
-
7
5 863
5

987 850
9
8
```

so what I am understanding is that it is breaking it up character by character, rather than by spaces. I know it can read in the whole line, as I can print the contents of the array in its entirety, but I dont know what I am doing wrong. 
I have also tried replacing value.split(" ") with:

```
value.gsub(/\s+/m, ' ').strip.split(" ")
value.split
value.split("\s")
```

Using RubyMine 2017.3.2

Comment: try `value = value.split(' ')`. `split` does not change the value of the variable it's called on.

Comment: as a side note, the reason why it looked like it was splitting it by characters is that in ruby, you can access a string like an array of characters. `"string"[1] #=> "t"`, you can also use ranges and regex with String#[]

Comment: Another side note: if you open a file with `File.open` without a block, get into the habit of closing it. `inputfile.close` will do it. There is a maximum on the amount of open files which can be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said in the comments, plus some other points, with an idiomatic code sample:

```
lines = File.readlines('myfile.in')

header_line, data_lines = lines[0], lines[1..-1]

num_cases = header_line.to_i

arrays_of_number_strings = data_lines.map(&:split)
arrays_of_numbers = arrays_of_number_strings.map do |array_of_number_strings|
    array_of_number_strings.map(&:to_i)
end

puts "#{num_cases} cases in file."
arrays_of_numbers.each { |a| p a }
```

- File.readlines is super handy!
- I don't think you were calling to_i on the header information, that
  will be important.
- The data_lines.map(&:split) will return an array of the numbers as strings, but then you'll need to convert those strings to numbers too.
- The `p a` in the final line will use the `Array#inspect` method, which is handy for viewing arrays as arrays, e.g. `[12, 34]`.